# How to pass argument with star to the next method?

Tags: scala

```
scala> class A (s: String*) { val l: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer[String](s) }
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
  found   : String*
  required: String
    class A(s: String*)  {val l: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer[String](s)}
```

Why is it not possible to pass the argument `s` to the apply method of ListBuffer[String] which is

```
def apply[A](elems: A*): CC[A] = { ... }
```

(Method `apply` from the `GenericCompanion.scala` )

The code `ListBuffer[String]("foo", "bar")` does work. But it seems I can not pass through the argument list of strings from `s` which is also `String*`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell Scala to unpack `s`:

```
ListBuffer[String](s: _*)
```

You also don't need the the explicit types:

```
scala> class A (s: String*) { val l = ListBuffer(s: _*) }
defined class A
```

Comment: I had similar case and your unpack solution solved the problem, however implicit conversion doesn't "kick in" (so I get type mismatch error). Is it possible to force implicit conversion with unpack feature ?